# How to make keyboard appear at top of screen

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, position, virtual-keyboard

When the user touches a UITextField a keyboard normally slides up from the bottom of the screen.

Is there a way to make the keyboard appear at the top of the screen instead of the bottom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that would be against the UI guidelines and since keyboards are made/controlled/managed by Apple there is no API to do this. At least, not a documented way I'm aware of.

Comment: Also on a personal note I can say it would annoy me to no end to have an app where the keyboard appeared in a non-standard position. Instant-delete :)

Comment: I agree completely with thenduks.  One of the strong points of the Apple domain is the strong UI guidelines.  I can't stand when people start screwing with things.. like moving buttons around from their normally expected positions.

Comment: It'd also be unusable!  Any UI below the keyboard would be obscured by my finger(s)/thumb(s) and I'd have to change the way I'm holding the device to be able to get to the keyboard.   Immediate delete.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to make the keyboard appear at the top of the screen instead of the bottom?

Easy. Turn your phone/iPod/iPad upside down!

*(technically this is an answer!)*